# Why does FireMonkey TListBox Animation prevent item deselection on Windows32 platform

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am new to FireMonkey (drawn by its new ability to work with Android).  I am trying to animate selection of an item with animation of the list box to reveal underlying content (a frequent pattern).  However, I am having trouble getting the list box to manage the deselection of the previously-selected item when I animate the disappearance of the list box.  Strangely, this only seems to happen on the Windows platform, and not on Android or iPad devices (or the iPad simulator).

To reproduce the problem (in RAD Studio XE5):

1) Create a new FireMonkey Mobile Application, selecting Tablet Master-Detail to use as a starting layout

2) Right-click on Target Platforms, and ***select 32-bit Windows***, to simplify debugging, and select it.

3) Add a new TListBox object, and drop it on the left portion of the window.

4) Use the Structure browser to move it to LeftLayout, making it's parent the LeftLayout.

5) Click on the ListBox1 object

6) Change the Align property to alClient, to fill the LeftLayout

7) In the ObjectInspector, select the Position Property, and the X Sub Property, and select Create New TFloatAnimation.  The FloatAnimation will be named FloatAnimation1

8) Create a new OnItemClick handler for ListBox1, and add the following code:

```
FloatAnimation1.StartFromCurrent := True;
FloatAnimation1.StopValue :=  0 - ((LeftLayout.Width) / 1);
FloatAnimation1.Start;
```

9) Create a new button, and place it on the toolbar at the top of the left window

10) Create a handler for the new button, and  add the following code:

```
FloatAnimation1.StartFromCurrent := True;
FloatAnimation1.StopValue := 0;
FloatAnimation1.Start;
```

11) Double Click on the ListBox to open the Items Designer, and click the AddItem button three times to add three TListBoxItems

12) Run the app.  Click on one of the three items in the ListBox.  The ListBox animates to the left, out of view.  Click on the button we added to get it back.  Click on the other items, and eventually, you will have all three items selected, even though MultiSelect is turned off for the ListBox1.

13) Stop the app.  Change the OnItemClick handler code by changing the "1" to a "2", so the ListBox will only move half of the way to the left.  Run the app again.  Now, when you click on the ListBox, only one item will be selected, and the previously-selected item will be deselected (as it should be for a single-selection list box).

Again, if I run this on iPad, iPad simulator, or an Android tablet, the ListBox works properly: when an item is clicked in the ListBox, the previously-selected item is deselected.

I can't be the first person to find this, since this sort of animation is so common in apps.  Why is the ListBox misbehaving, and why is it different in Windows32 if I animate it only part way off the screen, and why is it different in Windows32 than on the iPad or Android tablet?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, Win32 App with XE5 Update2, Listbox moving out left, then coming back but with remainders of the blue selection underlay.

What works (very dirty i know) for me, is starting a Timer right after starting the Animation. Timer Interval is 100ms

Code in Timer

```
if lb_liste.selected is TListBoxItem then
lb_liste.selected.isselected:= false;
```

//lb_liste is my Listbox, a problem could be that then no more item is selected, but that was fine for me.
I had this part in the OnProcess Event of the TFloatAnimation before, but strangely this caused an AV whenever i talked to a database over in another form before sliding back to my listbox.

For me this is clearly a bug in FMX, lets wait for XE6,7,8